# Posting Form in Webforms to AmazonPay API

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I'm using AmazonPay SDK for C# and I need to provide payment methods inside our payment flow.

In this first webform I have the payment button and which retrives the Order Reference ID. In the second I set the purchase details with API objects provided with the SDK on page load.

Now I want to post that information to Amazon MWS endpoint with the information that I collected from the purchase details. I want to be able to authorize this payment on click event, post the authorization request and get the response in the following page to finallize the payment and provide error handling feedback.

Example of the SetPurchaseDetails:

```
 public int SetPurchaseDetails(string amazonOrderReferenceId, string accessToken,  int amount, string storeName, string sellerOrderID, string sellerNote, out string AddressLine1, out string AddressLine2, out string AddressLine3)
        {   
            int ErrorCode = 0;
            string ErrorMsg = string.Empty;

            //Values to extract from the api calls
            AddressLine1 = string.Empty;
            AddressLine2 = string.Empty;
            AddressLine3 = string.Empty;



            try
            {
                SetOrderReferenceDetailsRequest orderReferenceDetailsRequest = new SetOrderReferenceDetailsRequest();
                orderReferenceDetailsRequest.WithAmazonOrderReferenceId(amazonOrderReferenceId)
                    .WithAmount(amount)
                    .WithSellerNote(sellerNote)
                    .WithSellerOrderId(sellerOrderID)
                    .WithStoreName(storeName);

                OrderReferenceDetailsResponse setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse = client.SetOrderReferenceDetails(orderReferenceDetailsRequest);
                bool orderReferenceDetailsResponseSuccess = setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetSuccess();  

                if (orderReferenceDetailsResponseSuccess == false)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("OrderReferenceDetails Response Returned error: " + setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetErrorCode() + setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetErrorMessage());
                    ErrorMsg = setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetErrorMessage();
                    ErrorCode = cError.ERR_AMAZONPAY_RESPONSE_FAILED;
                }

                ConfirmOrderReferenceRequest confirmOrderReferenceRequest = new ConfirmOrderReferenceRequest();
                confirmOrderReferenceRequest.WithAmazonOrderReferenceId(amazonOrderReferenceId);

                ConfirmOrderReferenceResponse confirmOrderReferenceResponse = client.ConfirmOrderReference(confirmOrderReferenceRequest);
                bool confirmResponseSuccess = confirmOrderReferenceResponse.GetSuccess();

                if (confirmResponseSuccess == false)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("ConfirmOrderReference Failed: " + confirmOrderReferenceResponse.GetErrorMessage() + confirmOrderReferenceResponse.GetErrorCode());


                }



                GetOrderReferenceDetailsRequest getOrderReferenceDetailsRequest = new GetOrderReferenceDetailsRequest();
                getOrderReferenceDetailsRequest.WithAmazonOrderReferenceId(amazonOrderReferenceId)
                    .WithAccessToken(accessToken);
                OrderReferenceDetailsResponse getOrderReferenceDetailsResponse = client.GetOrderReferenceDetails(getOrderReferenceDetailsRequest);

                AddressLine1 = getOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetAddressLine1();
                AddressLine2 = getOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetAddressLine2();
                AddressLine3 = getOrderReferenceDetailsResponse.GetAddressLine3();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               //testing 
               Debug.WriteLine(ex);


            }

            return ErrorCode;

        }
```

Example of Authorize:

```
public static int Authorize(string amazonOrderReferenceId, string authorizationReferenceId, decimal authorizationAmount, string CurrencyCode)
        {
            int ErrorCode = 0;
            string ErrorMsg = string.Empty;
            string authorizationState = string.Empty;


            try
            {
                if (authorizationReferenceId == null)
                {
                    ErrorMsg = "No authorization reference Id";
                    Debug.WriteLine(ErrorMsg);
                }

                AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = new AuthorizeRequest();
                authorizeRequest.WithAmazonOrderReferenceId(amazonOrderReferenceId)
                    .WithAuthorizationReferenceId(authorizationReferenceId)
                    .WithAmount(authorizationAmount);
                AuthorizeResponse authorizeResponse = client.Authorize(authorizeRequest);
                string authorizationId = authorizeResponse.GetAuthorizationId();

                if(authorizationId == null)
                {
                    ErrorMsg = "";
                    Debug.WriteLine(ErrorMsg);
                }

                authorizationState = authorizeResponse.GetAuthorizationState();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }





            return ErrorCode;

        }
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: I want to know how could I add a post to the information that I retrieve from the API calls. I can't put the Authorize in the Page_Load because it has to be linked to some sort of event. But then I cant seem to access some variables that are retrieved on page load from the API call Methods I created and exposed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should populate a hidden field that you can access on the postback. Something like this:

aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnAmazonOrderReferenceID" runat="server" />
```

Then in the SetPurchaseDetails method:

```
hdnAmazonOrderReferenceID.Value=amazonOrderReferenceId;
```

And in the Authorize method, instead of passing the amazonOrderReferenceId as a parameter, just grab it from the hidden field:

```
string amazonOrderReferenceId=hdnAmazonOrderReferenceID.Value;
```